# The volume of the region between two spheres and the upper nappe of a cone

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Guys I am really having trouble constraining  the region between these three surfaces. I am imagining a sort of "Dome", or a "muffin head" sort of shape. Is this correct ? Anyway, I need to be able to write the following volume integral in rectangular, cylindrical and spherical coordinates:

Consider the region that is between $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$, $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 9$, and finally above the upper nappe of the cone $z^2 = 3(x^2 + y ^2)$

upon further consideration, does the smaller sphere even matter ? wouldn't it just represent a hole in the larger sphere, an area im not even worried about finding the volume of ?

Anyway, thanks for looking!

Comment: Yes, the smaller sphere is just a hollow point within the larger sphere, so it will not be taken into consideration when calculating the volume. Only the volume between them will.

Comment: that makes sense... so perhaps i can just find the volume between the larger sphere and the cone... which is like a muffin top?

Comment: Yes, it will look like a muffin top, but you are not finding the volume between the larger sphere and the cone. You need to find the volume between the larger sphere and the smaller sphere **above** the cone.

Comment: Right so i need to take the integral over the top of the cone, the integral of the larger sphere's radius - the top of the cone, and a Pi/2 integral from the top of the cone to the z axis right ?

Comment: Not quite...it's pretty much impossible to explain in words xD Check my answer, and let me know if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First find where the cone intersects the inner sphere:

$$x^2+y^2=1-z^2$$

$$z^2=3-3z^2$$

$$z^2=\frac{3}{4}$$

This means that the radius of the boundary between the cone and inner sphere is $\frac{1}{2}$, and the radius of the boundary between the cone and the radius of the boundary for the outer sphere can be found to be $\frac{\sqrt{33}}{2}$, using the same process. Converting the sphere equations into cylindrical coordinates and using as bounds $0 \le \theta < 2\pi$ and $\frac{1}{2}\le r < \frac{\sqrt{33}}{2}$, the volume integral is as follows:

$$V=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{\sqrt{33}}{2}}(\sqrt{9-r^2}-\sqrt{1-r^2})rdr d\theta$$

A similar procedure can be followed to find the integral in rectangular and spherical coordinates.

Comment: thanks for this... i was pretty close in my mind. i should be able to do the rest! +1 for you =D

Comment: @Neo Glad to help!

Comment: zetta, are u sure this is volume and not area ?

Comment: @Neo crap, you're right, I forgot to add the r term. I've corrected it, see my latest edit.

Comment: what about the z term ? thats what im confused about!

Comment: The entire function under the integral is the z term. So $z=\sqrt{9-r^2}-\sqrt{1-r^2}$. Consider the integral of a single variable function, you never see a y term in it, right? That's because the whole function under the integral **is** the y term.